# Largest floating point value that can be squared

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, numeric-limits

I have a function that takes in an optional distance parameter `dist`, but my algorithm works with squared distances. If the user does not specify any value, I want `dist` to be as large a number as possible.

```
Result foo(double dist = std::sqrt(std::numeric_limits<double>::max())) const;
```

Is the code above safe, or will it blow up because of rounding errors? Would it be better to use something (even) uglier like

```
Result foo(double dist = std::sqrt(std::numeric_limits<double>::max() - 100)) const;
```

Comment: Not sure whether your algorithm could work with it, but why not `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity` ? It will return that it's larger than any number in comparisons and it doesn't get any worse when you square it.

Comment: oh, i didn't know I could square `std::numeric_limits<double::infinity`. This is exactly what I need then. Thanks!

Comment: Let's make it an answer then.

Comment: Re “It will return that it's larger than any number in comparisons”: ∞ is a number in floating-point, and it is not larger than itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're careful, you can use `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity` . It will do the right thing in comparisons and if you square it, it remains infinite.